# Consent issues with graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I registered an app in AD with these delegated permissions. I'm creating an app to activate your PIM role. I'm using Power automate and Power Apps for this.

I'm noticing the token doesn't have any permissions set to it as I'm receiving a "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." when I try to filter for a specific role. I double checked and have the correct clientid and secret for the token. I also have the correct permissions set to the azure app and consent was granted.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

My Directory role is: Security Admin, Cloud App Admin, Application Admin. Do I need to be global admin?

This does work when I make the calls from Microsoft Graph Explorer.

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory
RoleManagement.Read.Directory
RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory
User.Read
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to consent the permission as application not delegated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).